# Failed to collect dependencies at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.8.1

Tags: maven, spring-boot

We are using maven 3.3.3 version in build system, whereas in local system we have maven 3.5.0 version. With 3.5.0 version of maven everything works perfectly, it downloads all the jars. But with maven 3.3.3 we are getting below error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to collect dependencies at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.8.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.8.1: Could not transfer artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:pom:2.8.1 from/to central (http://build.dlh.de/artifactory/libs-release): Failed to transfer file: http://build.dlh.de/artifactory/libs-release/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/jackson-dataformat-xml/2.8.1/jackson-dataformat-xml-2.8.1.pom. Return code is: 400 , ReasonPhrase:Bad Request. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project lhopenapi-actuators: Could not resolve dependencies for project xxx:xxx:jar:1.0.0: Failed to collect dependencies at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.8.1
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:221)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:257)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven33Launcher.main(Maven33Launcher.java:129)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main.launch(Maven33Main.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:139)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:70)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:210)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:53)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:364)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Could you please help with below queries:

1. Is maven version related to other application jars? like maven 3.5.0 version can download 2.8.1 version of jackson-dataformat-xml and 3.3.3 cannot download?
2. How do we manage such dependencies if any?

Please help us to resolve this issue.

Additional information updated below as per suggestion:

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>lhopenapi-actuators</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>Custom Actuators for Spring Boot</name>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
        <artifactId>lhopenapi-common-properties</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria>e1</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria>
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.ruleKey>squid:S00101</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.ruleKey>
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.resourceKey>**/*RS.java</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.resourceKey>
        <spring.version>4.3.11.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jackson.version>2.8.1</jackson.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.19</slf4j.version>
        <javax.servlet.version>3.0.1</javax.servlet.version>
        <spring.boot.version>1.5.7.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
        <lhopenapi.errors.version>1.0.0</lhopenapi.errors.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Also another info is jackson-databind gets downloaded properly along with all other jars except jackson-dataformat-xml. We are using jenkins to build this package.

User Settings.xml:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <localRepository>C:\Users\anil\.m2\repository</localRepository>
    <interactiveMode />
    <usePluginRegistry />
    <offline>false</offline>
    <pluginGroups />


    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>central</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <name>releases</name>
                    <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: 1. There is nothing like that, If you see the Effective pom version mentioned for jackson-dataformat-xml is 2.8.10 for Spring boot 1.5.9.RELEASE. 2. Check your Pom and If you paste Pom along with question might help in answering this.

Comment: Added pom and additional info. Please help

Comment: I thought you are using Spring Boot but all your dependencies are using Spring core dependencies ?? It should not impact but can you change them. Suggestion: Use Spring Initializr and try with new project.

Comment: @JaisAnkit i did not understand this. "I thought you are using Spring Boot but all your dependencies are using Spring core dependencies ??" Please explain as i am new to springboot

Answer (score 0):

To answer your queries:

> Is maven version related to other application jars? like maven 3.5.0
>   version can download 2.8.1 version of jackson-dataformat-xml and 3.3.3
>   cannot download?

No, maven should work perfectly.

> How do we manage such dependencies if any?

Probably, it is not a dependency problem, but with the system/client tools.
Please try `mvn clean install` from the console and make sure that you have repository access.

**EDIT: Based on OP comment**

> Updated problem statement with settings.xml please help. And i am yet
>   to verify settings.xml on the build server. But it is able to download
>   all other packages except this one is my worry.

The repository mentioned in the `settings.xml` is `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/`, which do have the jar.

[image]

Comment: `mvn clean install` is what we are using.  Also to answer your other suggestion, it is able to download all other jars except this one.

Comment: Can you please post the content of `settings.xml` in `.m2` folder. I want to know the maven repository config on the machine. Please check if the `settings.xml` configuration is same on both the machine.

Comment: Updated problem statement with settings.xml please help. And i am yet to verify settings.xml on the build server. But it is able to download all other packages except this one is my worry.

Comment: @AnilKumarP The settings at your local machine is all set, hence it is good (See the updated answer). Why I am asking for the build server setting? Because sometime build servers are behind proxy and have repository pointing to a controlled enterprise specific maven. In that case, the enterprise maven repo may not have the central maven artifacts (in this case `2.8.1` version of `jackson-dataformat-xml` ) cached. It may have a different version (or missing), which limits you. Ideally all `dev` machine `.m2` folder should have the same `settings.xml`as of build server to maintain compatibility.

Comment: Thank you. I am yet to get access to check settings.xml in build server. I will look into this and accept this as answer once this is solved.